# Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'UITabBarController?'

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, type-safety

I am trying to instantiate a `UITabBarController` from an identifier, however am facing the following error:

`Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'UITabBarController'`

Here is the offending the code:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("LoginPage") == true
    {
        tabBarController = k_Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarController")  //------Error Showed in this Line.
        self.window!.rootViewController = tabBarController
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Selected)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 246 / 255.0, green: 206 / 255.0, blue: 206 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)], forState: .Normal)
        isFirstPage = true
    }
```

Comment: What is the error please post .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer**: You are attempting an implicit downcast from type `UIViewController` to a subclass `UITabBarController`. The compiler is right to stop you from doing that. You must **explicitly** attempt a forced downcast, by changing

`k_Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarController")`

to the following:

`k_Storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabbarController") as! UITabBarController`

If you still  don't understand the error, think about it this way: the compiler has no way to guarantee that the `UIViewController` returned from `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is a `UITabBarController`. You must **explicitly** guarantee it.

Comment: Yes I Understand and thanks for Clear My Doubt @Vatsal Manot.